# Java EE i18n without property files

Tags: java, internationalization, properties

normally I place my translations etc in `properties` - e.g. `message_de.properties` etc. I'm facing now a situation where I have to provide this data in a database. (Translations will be imported/edited in an other system)

Is there a common way/best practises to use a database table for messages in my webapp? One way I would thinking of was to build `properties` from the database but this seems not the right way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `ResourceBundle` doesn't need to be based on a properties file, you can write your own implementation and back them with JDBC or whatever tickles your fancy. The [`ResourceBundle` javadoc page](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) has an example on how to make a custom implementation.

Answer (score 1):

To me it sounds like exporting the database to properties files *would* be the correct way to go. It's simple and I would assume the database does not change that often? The export can then be automated different ways.